# Android Service Not Retaining Data onRestart

Tags: android, service, crash, broadcastreceiver, locationmanager

I am using an Arraylist to store user selected alert-locations and am comparing these "locations" with the user's present location in my service via a broadcaster.

On force crashing the application, I am able to restart the service but the data in the Arraylist created for comparison disappears and hence, the service cannot find the preexisting data.

I have no clue what I am missing? Here is my method used for saving the location and requestID in a ArrayList.

```
private void addProximityAlert(double latitude, double longitude,int requestID) {
     Location alertLoc=new Location("C");
     IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(proximitysd);
     registerReceiver(mybroadcast, filter);
     Intent intent = new Intent(proximitysd); 
     //Saving requestID in an array  
     requestNo.add(Integer.valueOf(requestID)); 
     alertLoc.setLatitude(latitude);
     alertLoc.setLongitude(longitude);
     //Saving alertLoc in an array
     proximitylocation.add(alertLoc);   
     PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,     requestID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
     Log.v("add Proximity ","Pendingintentcreated");
}
```

p.s. I am not intending to use locationmanager.addproximityalert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use shared preferences to save data when your app force closes. [This](http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/12260/android-sharedpreferences-example/) is as good an tutorial as any.

Comment: SQlite is also an option http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: I used data serialization to save the data on adding proximity alert. On system crash or restart, i restored the data back into the ArrayList. Thanks a lot for your lead. Helped loads!!

Comment: Pleasure, accept the answer or add the method you used so that it can help other users in the future. Good luck with the rest of your project ;)